# Image pointStyle doesn't load on initial chart render?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I want to load an image for one of the data points in a Scatter chart. The problem I have is the image doesn’t load on the initial page/chart render. Image only appears when you click/interact with the chart.
I am using `react-chartjs-2`, any suggestions would be appreciated.

I’ve tried the following (snippet)

```
import { Scatter, Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";

const chartReference = useRef();
const myImage = new Image(25, 35); 
myImage.src = '/img/myimage.svg';
  
const chartData = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'my Image',
        data: [{ x: dummyData, y: 25 }],
        pointStyle: myImage,
        radius: 1,
        pointRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        type: 'line',
    }],
}

 return (
    <Scatter
        height={height}
        width={width}
        data={chartData}
        options={options}
        plugins={[Zoom]}
        ref={chartReference}
        redraw={true} 
    />
```

I also through of this but where should do I place this?

```
chartReference.current.chartInstance.data.datasets[0].pointStyle = myImage; 
chartReference.current.chartInstance.update();
```

If you manage to solve that I would like to ask a part 2 question that is the when you pan the chart unlike the built in `data pointStyle` the image goes off the y-axis. It only hide when at the charts actual width

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you define the `Image` inside the component `constructor`...

```
constructor() {
  super();
  const myImage = new Image(25, 35);
  myImage.src = "/img/myimage.svg";
```

and create the `Scatter` chart inside the `render` method.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Scatter
        data={this.state.chartData }
        options={this.state.chartOptions}
        ...
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-vspuvq?file=index.js).

Comment: thanks. But I don't want to use class. I'm working with function component with React Hooks.