# Image as a pointStyle with ChartJS in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using `chartjs`/`react-chartjs-s` to draw some plots in React/NextJS. I want to use an image for the `pointStyle` for one plot in specific. In plain JavaScript, an image can be created using `const i = new Image()` and used as a `pointStyle` in ChartJS.

In React I get an error `ReferenceError: Image is not defined`. If I try to import `Image` from `next/image` and use that, then the image does not appear on initial render (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231233/image-pointstyle-doesnt-load-on-initial-chart-render) which interestingly *can* use `new Image()`), and if I click on a datum on the chart I get an error `Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

**TLDR: Does anyone know how to use an image/icon as a `pointStyle` using Next.js, ChartJS, and react-chartjs-2?** Thanks!

I'm using:

1. `react` v. 18.2.0
2. `react-dom` v. 18.2.0
3. `next` v 13.0.05
4. `chart.js` v. 4.1.1
5. `react-chartjs-2` v. 5.1.0

Comment: Please have a look at this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/radar-chart-react-shyv49?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @DreamBold thanks for the help! I moved the `new Image()` statement into my component return, but now I am getting an error that says `TypeError: Cannot add property src, obejct is not extensible`

Comment: Can you replicate your code in the codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wave-qhgzv0?file=/src/App.tsx Here's the typescript template

Comment: @DreamBold I created a component from your code which was working fine. After making some edits, I again got the `Image not defined` error. I `Cntl + Z`'ed until I got back to your original code (and saved), and the error persisted. I am completely at a loss for what could be causing this.

Comment: @DreamBold it appears that whenever I refresh the browser I get the `ReferenceError: Image not defined` error

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#:~:text=Here%20is%20an%20example%20of%20using%20a%20custom%20loader%3A Here's how to import an image in next.js. Next.js is SSR(server-side rendering), and that's why you see the error

Comment: @DreamBold - thanks for that. The only problem now is that ChartJS expects an inbuilt JS object and not a Next <Image> object. Either way, thanks for your help! It's sincerely appreciated. I'll close out this question because the true answer is not really related to my initial question. Thanks!

Comment: You'd better add the solution to this question when you fix it so it can help the others. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

`new Image()` reference the DOM, but since Next uses SSR, you have to utilize the `useRef`, `useState`, and `useEffect` hooks to circumvent the issue of trying to access the DOM.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "chart.js";
import { Radar } from "../node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist";

ChartJS.register(
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

function App() {
  // useRef lets you reference a DOM object, persistent between renders
  const ref = useRef();
  const [onClient, setOnClient] = useState();
  
  // On first render, set onClient flag to true
  useEffect(() => {
    setOnClient(true);
  }, []);

  // On first render, set the current value of the ref to the image
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = new Image(25, 25);
    ref.current.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXQrT.png";
  }, []);

  const data = {
    labels: ["Business 1", "Business 2", "Business 3"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Number of Businesses",
        data: [1300, 400, 160],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        // Set the value of pointStyle to the ref value
        pointStyle: ref.current
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      // Return the graph if rendering is happening on the client
      {onClient && <Radar data={data} />}

      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Label" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Dataset" />
        <button>Add Data</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```